# Database with application, no need of server, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I'd like to ask you about the simplest way how to have a small database with my application in c#, without using a server. Im using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and I used to work with Local Database and Ado.Net data entity model, but I can't see it here anymore.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx).

> LocalDB is created specifically for developers. It is very easy to
>   install and requires no management, yet it offers the same T-SQL
>   language, programming surface and client-side providers as the regular
>   SQL Server Express. In effect the developers that target SQL Server no
>   longer have to install and manage a full instance of SQL Server
>   Express on their laptops and other development machines. Moreover, if
>   the simplicity (and limitations) of LocalDB fit the needs of the
>   target application environment, developers can continue using it in
>   production, as LocalDB makes a pretty good embedded database too.

Here's a walkthrough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx

Comment: Thank you, how can I install that?

Comment: I added a walkthrough link to my answer.

Comment: I am new to this topic, but I've read that "mdf" can't work without the server. So how is it?

Comment: My information says it can.  If you still don't want to touch .mdf anyway, then you could use sqlite, which does not use mdf at all.